# How do i remove all useless values from Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts

I use Chart.js diagram and it contains some float values which i want to hide to get only 0, 1.0, 2.0. How can i do it?

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of the inicial values and the end result

Comment: this is an array: https://gyazo.com/bd0cadefa74ae36a23bd6860c5d32524

Comment: That array is equal to ``[1,1,2,0,1,1,0,2]``. What is the end result you expect?

Comment: The array is corrent, I just want to remove unused values from the chart - like 1.6, 1.8

Answer (score 2):

For this solution you need to things:

1. The `filter()` function
2. `%` modul operand

With the `filter()` function, you can evaluate each number. Those values that pass the test will form a new array.

Using `%` modul you can create a test. What modul lets you do is get the remainder of a division

2 % 1 = 0

2.1 % 1 = 0.1

This way we can filter the values that have a reminder when divided by 1

Hope this helps :>

```js
arr = [1,1,2,0,1,1,0,2,1.6, 1.8]

let cleanArr = arr.filter(num=> num%1==0)

console.log('Initial: ' + arr)
console.log('Filter: ' + cleanArr)
```

Comment: Wow, this is right solution, but not for my problem. We did not understand each other :) I have the array that always has 7 elements and these elements are always int. I show each element on the chart, but the chart shows much more elements for a scale, i suppose. I am talking about chart axes, not about array, and i want to remove all except 0, 1.0 and 2.0 from the axe: https://gyazo.com/dfbf25839c47815d2c0023e18f34531e

Comment: I see, can you add a live example of your chart

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpavpy8w/ there are a little bit other values but there you can see these values added for scale too - like 1.5 or 0.5